# SSRS Report is throwing runtime error from Report Manager

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssrs-2008, reporting-services

When i am running few reports that have 3+ parameters having many values (>1000) then sometime the report is throwing the runtime error as described below;

**

```
Webpage error details
User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0; InfoPath.2; MS-RTC LM 8; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E)
Timestamp: Wed, 8 Feb 2012 14:34:12 UTC
Message: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: An unknown error occurred while processing the request on the server. The status code returned from the server was: 500
Line: 5
Char: 62099
Code: 0
URI: http://pit-as-sqldbp03/Reports/ScriptResource.axd?d=LSM-sIjIq1I3gqXWAV4-sDoSzT66sEJz0Rf8Iko-xIr2Gk6IIEtfrAeXLKMBVKsD2PT8EUa4dck9Tp5I-r0TEVxM92WQtwDjvg68Dmnv4K3LrV1y76r-Wu_gAfNLZfJynNkH3Pmt7ock4K7L4NUbzk8TrdU1&t=ffffffff8dc250fc
```

**

Can anyone help me for this? What is the cause & solution of the problem causing such error??

Please help me!!!

Comment: Please guide me. Any comment would be helpful

Comment: Thanks for the vote-up. Awaiting some helpful inputs

Comment: I can't answer your question directly, but there are lots of Google hits for that error message, sometimes involving SSRS and sometimes not. 500 is presumably HTTP Error 500, i.e. it's an application error in SSRS for some reason. So a good place to start would be reviewing the SSRS and Windows logs for more information, and also work through the Google hits to see if anything matches your situation. Have you done this already and if so, what additional information have you gathered?

Comment: I have checked Database logs & they are empty. I googled for this and found that increasing the maxRequestLength Parameter in web.config could be helpful but not very sure about the same.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10911610/ssrs-webpage-error-status-code-500

Answer (score 0):

Your problem description is way to thin to give you any definitive answer.  But, I'd recommend turning on SQLProfiler while you're calling your *.axd page and tracing the SQL that's getting generated.  Try to find combinations of params that consistently work and then those that consistently fail.  Trace that to the raw SQL from Profiler and then run that manually in SSMS to see if you see any errors.

Comment: Thanks sisdog! That can be great troubleshooting help! Get back to you for more help on this,if any.

Answer (score 0):

This was nothing related to error in SSRS. Configuration change was required here

Comment: See here for step by step guide to resolving this problem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10911610/ssrs-webpage-error-status-code-500/10947474#10947474