# SSRS webpage error status code 500

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, reporting-services

Have deployed numerous report parts which reference the same view however one of them is failing to run on the server, I think it may be due to having parameters in place with all sorts of characters in them. This is the error message I get:

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to get around this.

```
Webpage error details

User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E)
Timestamp: Wed, 6 Jun 2012 08:34:05 UTC


Message: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: An unknown error occurred while processing the request on the server. The status code returned from the server was: 500
Line: 5
Char: 62099
Code: 0
URI: http://mysqlserver/Reports/ScriptResource.axd?d=XwwW1tMwtFzdBQ9-6KriOz3q0Wkgg-xPb7EWT8HUhJXnf8sz46FbnRIo5guVNx1JC-QFapCZ-oQvTRpjjwXFYypY46ebyJBSDV8_0QBsVijeeYDDkZolFtJT35QxeGTEsgsKCpzrB-ZJiu83PMYBwOjrroQ1&t=ffffffffb868b5f4
```

Comment: May be this link can help u resolve the issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9206657/ssrs-report-is-throwing-runtime-error-from-report-manager

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This problem is being caused by SQL server stopping a report being run because the request length exceeds a certain amount.

**The solution to this is as follows:**

Locate the web.config files for the ReportManager & ReportServer.

These should be found somewhere like this:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS10_50.MSSQLSERVER\Reporting Services\ReportManager\Web.config

C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS10_50.MSSQLSERVER\Reporting Services\ReportServer\Web.config
```

Once located you need to edit the web.config files for both and add the following bit of code:

```
<appSettings>
<add key="aspnet:IgnoreFormActionAttribute" value="true" />
<add key="aspnet:MaxHttpCollectionKeys" value="100000" />
</appSettings>
```

These app settings should be added between between /system.web and runtime nodes, so it should look something like the following:

```
</system.web>
<appSettings>
<add key="aspnet:IgnoreFormActionAttribute" value="true" />
<add key="aspnet:MaxHttpCollectionKeys" value="100000" />
</appSettings>
<runtime>
```

**NOTE:**
The ReportManager may already have an app settings node so you will only need to paste the two add key lines.

The ReportServer will more than likely require all 4 lines (including the open and close appsettings nodes.

Comment: If having trouble with maxRequestLength, try: https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/484431/report-builder-deployment-error-maximum-request-length-exceeded

Comment: this does not work for me.  if i run the process locally in my visual studio 2015 using my local iis express on ssrs 2012 report will render.  If i run it on the web server it will timeout.  I have done every suggestion on the internet including above, even started with a brand new application pool and nothing works.  exactly 2 minutes and loading disappears, and i get  
An unknown error occurred while processing the request on the server. The status code returned from the server was: 500  from the most updated version of MicrosoftAjaxWebForms.js that im posting this message

Comment: @MichaelRudnerEvanchik this is not a timeout issue

Comment: @MichaelRudnerEvanchik Did you ever solve this? We're facing the exact same issue. Works locally when dubugging, but after 2 minutes craps out with the same 500 error when deployed. I've tried almost everything timeout etc I can find to no avail.