# WebRequest for SSRS report- gives 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: c#, reporting-services, webrequest

Trying to execute an SSRS report via a WebRequest object. The call to get the response gives a "500 Internal Server Error" with no more information (I check parameter values etc are valid in the browser)

I debugged to grab the url, and pasted it into the browser and it worked successfully.

```
http://devBI/ReportServer?%2fSSRS+Project%2fValuationReport&rs:Command=Render&rs:Format=EXCEL&ReportDate=23/06/2013&ClientCode=QWECT&IsEOM=0
```

The code in question is:

```
WebRequest Request = HttpWebRequest.Create(reportUrl);
Request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
log.Debug("Credentials for request: " + Request.Credentials.ToString());
if (config.UseInfiniteTimeout)
{
    Request.Timeout = System.Threading.Timeout.Infinite;
}
else
{
    Request.Timeout = config.TimeoutSeconds * 1000;
}

Request.Method = "GET";
try
{
    HttpWebResponse Response = (HttpWebResponse)Request.GetResponse();
    using (Stream ResponseStream = Response.GetResponseStream())
    {
        string responseString;
        StreamHelper.CopyStream(Response.GetResponseStream(), out responseString);
        ResponseStream.Flush();
        ResponseStream.Close();

        log.Debug("Response string: " + responseString);
        return responseString;
    }
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    log.Error("Error encountered during WebRequest/Response: " + e.ToString());
    throw;
}
```

Comment: The following link did not work for me, but this might be useful to others who encounter 500 errors and come across my question: (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10911610/ssrs-webpage-error-status-code-500)

Comment: Could you try enabling the [http log](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630443.aspx)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer NOT ALL CLIENTS ARE THE SAME! (date format was the issue).

The date format allowed when testing in the browser (Internet Explorer) is `dd/MM/yyyy`

The date format allowed when called from Visual Studio is `MM/dd/yyyy`

Note: I do not know where this behavior could be changed, and cannot find any documentation of this SSRS 'feature'

Comment: It is possible that your server and your development systems are not configured with the same region format. It looks like your development machine is set to use american format.

Comment: Just double checked this and my machine (and the server) are set to Australian (NON USA) region. I am guessing my code is somehow reverting to a default of USA rather than using System setting, but I don't think I will have time to chase down where.